# Invoking instance func is my bug, right?

Tags: ios, swift

I've defined the following class; trying to test it.
But when I invoke a function with seemingly correct 
formal and actual parameters, Swift 1.2 reports
**Expected Declaration**.

I have no idea what's wrong with it.

*Note: I made the class because I was having trouble getting an array passed by reference (inout / &) to propagate the changes made in the called function. That was weird too.

```
    class TableData {

        var dataArrays = [UITableView : [String]]()

        func addArray(obj : UITableView, _ initialValues : [String] ) {
            dataArrays[obj] = [String]()
            dataArrays[obj]?.extend(initialValues)
        }
        func swapItems(tv : UITableView, _ rowa: Int, _ rowb : Int) {
            var item1 = dataArrays[tv]![rowa] as String
            var item2 = dataArrays[tv]![rowb] as String
            dataArrays[tv]![rowa] = item2
            dataArrays[tv]![rowb] = item1
        }

        func moveItem(srcTbl: UITableView, _ srcRow : Int, _ dstTbl: UITableView, _ dstRow: Int) {
            var item = getItem(srcTbl, srcRow)
            insertItem(dstTbl, dstRow, item)
            deleteItem(srcTbl, srcRow)
        }

       func insertItem(tv : UITableView, _ row: Int, _ value: String) {
           dataArrays[tv]!.insert(value, atIndex: row)
       }

        func getItem(tv: UITableView, _ row: Int) -> String {
           return dataArrays[tv]![row]
        }

        func deleteItem(tv: UITableView, _ row: Int) {
            dataArrays[tv]!.removeAtIndex(row)
        }

        func count(tv: UITableView) -> Int {
            return dataArrays[tv]!.count
        }

        func printItems(tv: UITableView, title: String? = nil) {
            if title != nil {
                println("\(title):")
            }
            for i in 0..<dataArrays[tv]!.count {
                var item = dataArrays[tv]![i]
                println("\(i) \"\(item)\"")
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: that's not how you initialize `tableData`. move `addArray` calls into `init`

Comment: But why do I need init() if the one var definition self-initializes?  init is needed only if there are uninitialized variables.  I should be able to have a function that allows me to add new arrays that I couldn't do at init time, right?  I'm trying to figure out specifically what is wrong with this code.

Comment: I tried it in a playground and it worked without error. The use of anonymous parameters isn't very good style

Comment: I don't think you need to use `init` to do the work - there could be multiple tableview's data in this object so the addArray is OK, however I would question if the tableview is the best key to use.  It would be more abstract if you could use some other key and then associate the key with the tableview

Comment: @paulw11 - Why is tableView not a good key to use? As long as it conforms to the hashable protocol it should be fine, right?  Right now I'm testing the bigger picture, the Drag & Drop thing and this wrapper is just kind of quick/temporary. When it's working I'll consider making it more formal.

Comment: It will work and I appreciate that this is just a temp fix, so it is probably OK - From a design point of view, however it is cleaner for your data model to be independent of the view, so you would have, say a "widgets" table and a "sizes" table and a "colors" table or whatever. You would then associate each tableview with the string key and use this string to access the data model.  This is cleaner because you can persist string keys if you need to

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, nevermind.  I had to move the invocation tableData.addArray() into viewDidLoad().

I know better than that.  Oh well, Long day.

I'm so used to initializing some variables out of a function in Swift (so as not to push everything into init()).